# Where can I find accurate London bus route maps?

Tags: public-transport, london, buses, maps, tfl

Is there any place where I can find the geographically accurate route followed by a specified bus route in London?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### TFL Website

Have you tried [TFL's bus map webpage](https://tfl.gov.uk/maps/bus)?

#### Bus Maps by City Area

It allows you to download PDF's with bus maps by city area ([Central](https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/central-london-bus-map.pdf), [North West](https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/north-west-london-bus-map.pdf), [North East](https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/north-east-london-bus-map.pdf), [South West](https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/south-west-london-bus-map.pdf), [South East](https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/south-east-london-bus-map.pdf)).

#### Interactive Maps

You can also view maps interactively from the site. Zoom in to view the bus stops, click on the bus stop you need, and zoom out to see the bus routes. Below is a screenshot for the routes passing via Trafalgar Square stop 'T':

[image: TFL bus routes via Trafalgar Square stop 'T']

#### Bus Spider Maps

Finally, the website allows you to [search for and download bus spider maps](https://tfl.gov.uk/maps_/bus-spider-maps). You can search for the individual bus line, or by borough. Below is what [the spider map of the 222 at Heathrow Airport North](https://tfl.gov.uk/cdn/static/cms/documents/bus-route-maps/heathrowairportnorth-a4-0815.pdf) looks like:

[image: TFL spider map of the 222 at Heathrow Airport North]

Comment: Perfect. I had that page, but hadn't zoomed in far enough to actually select stops and routes